# Webbrowser when navigate Download dialog opened

Tags: c#

program.cs code

```
static void Main()
    {
        CheckHWID();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var lgn = new Form2();
        lgn.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(FormClosed);
        lgn.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
    static void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form)sender).FormClosed -= FormClosed;
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) Application.ExitThread();
        else Application.OpenForms[0].FormClosed += FormClosed;
    }
```

program.cs and form 2 -> form1(webbrowser)

```
      Form1 fr = new Form1();
        fr.Show();
        this.Close();
```

form1.code

```
browser.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

when navigate browser
open download websource dialog 
i don't know why this happened

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the dialog? What happens if you change the URL to `https://google.com`?

Comment: when change url just download dialog by chrome

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the dialog?